# QGraphicsScene changing objects when selected

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a [`QGraphicsScene`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) containing some simple objects (in this simplified example circles) that I want to change into other objects (here squares) when selected.  More specifically I'd like to have parent objects which don't draw themselves, they are drawn by their child objects,  and under various circumstances, but in particular when the parent objects are selected, I'd like the set of child objects to change.  This is a nice conceptual framework for the overall app I am working on.

So I've implemented this in `PySide` and I thought it was working fine: the circles change nicely into squares when you click on them.

Until I use `RubberBandDrag` selection in the view.  This causes an instant segfault when the rubber band selection reaches the parent object and the selection changes.  Presumably this is being triggered because the rubber band selection in QT is somehow keeping a pointer to the child item which is disappearing before the rubber band selection action is complete.

Simplified code below - test it by first clicking on the object (it changes nicely) then dragging over the object - segfault:

```
from PySide import QtCore,QtGui

class SceneObject(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self, scene = scene)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemHasNoContents, True)
        self.updateContents()

    def updateContents(self):
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        for c in self.childItems():
            self.scene().removeItem(c)

        if self.isSelected():
            shape_item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem()
        else:
            shape_item = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem()
        shape_item.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        shape_item.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemStacksBehindParent,True)
        shape_item.setPen(QtGui.QPen("green"))
        shape_item.setRect(QtCore.QRectF(0,0,10,10))
        shape_item.setParentItem(self)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if self.scene() != None:
            if change == QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedHasChanged:
                self.updateContents()
                return
        return super(SceneObject,self).itemChange(change, value)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.childrenBoundingRect()


class Visualiser(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Visualiser,self).__init__()

        self.viewer = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.viewer.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.viewer)
        self.viewer.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene())

        parent_item = SceneObject(self.viewer.scene())
        parent_item.setPos(50,50)



app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mainwindow = Visualiser()
mainwindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

So questions:

Have I just made a mistake that can be straightforwardly fixed?

Or is removing objects from the scene not allowed when handling an `ItemSelectedHasChanged` event?

Is there a handy workaround?  Or what's a good alternative approach?  I could replace the `QGraphicsRectItem` with a custom item which can be drawn either as a square or a circle but that doesn't conveniently cover all my use cases.  I can see that I could make that work but it will certainly not be as straightforward.

**EDIT** - Workaround:

It is possible to prevent this failing by preserving the about-to-be-deleted object for a while.  This can be done by something like this:

```
def updateContents(self):
    self.prepareGeometryChange()
    self._temp_store = self.childItems()
    for c in self.childItems():
        self.scene().removeItem(c)

    ...
```

However, this is ugly code and increases the memory usage for no real benefit.  Instead I have moved to using the `QGraphicsScene.selectionChanged` signal as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081281/1295678) answer.

Comment: What version of PySide and python are you using? I just tried it and had no problems.

Comment: Good question - Python 2.7.11- PySide 1.2.4 - all on Windows 8.1

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.13 and PySide 1.2.4, what is your OS ?, are you running it through an IDE ?, if so what is it?

Comment: No IDE, windows 8.1 (sorry added that to the previous comment).  Usually it crashes absolutely immediately but sometimes I need to drag the rubber band over it a few times.

Comment: In linux it works very well, it only generates a warning in the line: `self.viewer.scene().addItem(parent_item)` since when you pass the scene, it automatically attaches it, but it works great.

Comment: I recommend you try on other machines with windows, in addition to telling us how you have installed pyside.

Comment: PySide installed from PyPI wheel.  Other machines with the same setup behave the same.  I can probably find a Windows 10 machine to try but otherwise I don't have a lot of scope (standard corporate build :-().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debugged it. Reproduced on Lunix

```
1  qFatal(const char *, ...) *plt                                                                                                  0x7f05d4e81c40 
2  qt_assert                                                                                     qglobal.cpp                  2054 0x7f05d4ea197e 
3  QScopedPointer<QGraphicsItemPrivate, QScopedPointerDeleter<QGraphicsItemPrivate>>::operator-> qscopedpointer.h             112  0x7f05d2c767ec 
4  QGraphicsItem::flags                                                                          qgraphicsitem.cpp            1799 0x7f05d2c573b8 
5  QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea                                                              qgraphicsscene.cpp           2381 0x7f05d2c94893 
6  QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent                                                                 qgraphicsview.cpp            3257 0x7f05d2cca553 
7  QGraphicsViewWrapper::mouseMoveEvent                                                          qgraphicsview_wrapper.cpp    1023 0x7f05d362be83 
8  QWidget::event                                                                                qwidget.cpp                  8374 0x7f05d2570371
```

qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsscene.cpp:2381

```
void QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea(const QPainterPath &path, Qt::ItemSelectionMode mode,
                                      const QTransform &deviceTransform)
{
...
    // Set all items in path to selected.
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, items(path, mode, Qt::DescendingOrder, deviceTransform)) {
        if (item->flags() & QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable) { // item is invalid here
            if (!item->isSelected()) 
                changed = true;
            unselectItems.remove(item);
            item->setSelected(true);
        }
    }
```

They are using `items()` function to find a list of items under the rubber band selection. But if one item while processing deletes something the item pointer just becomes invalid. And next call to `item->flags()` causes the crash.

As alternative you could use `QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged` signal. It's emitted only once per selection change.

Looks like it's not expected by Qt to have some major changes in `itemChange`

---

Behind of this here is common mistake you have with `prepareGeometryChange()` call.

It's designed to be called right before changing `boundingRect`. Bounding rect should be the old one when `prepareGeometryChange` called and new one right after.

So that's could happen:

In `updateContents`:

```
self.prepareGeometryChange(); # calls boundingRect. old value returned
...
shape_item.setParentItem(self); # could call the boundingRect. but still old value returned!
```

After child added it calls `boundingRect` again but value unexpected different.

As a solution you can add a variable

```
def updateContents(self):
    for c in self.childItems():
        self.scene().removeItem(c)

    if self.isSelected():
        shape_item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem()
    else:
        shape_item = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem()
    shape_item.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)

    shape_item.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemStacksBehindParent,True)
    shape_item.setPen(QtGui.QPen("green"))
    shape_item.setRect(QtCore.QRectF(0,0,10,10))
    shape_item.setParentItem(self) 

    self.prepareGeometryChange();
    self._childRect = self.childrenBoundingRect()

def boundingRect(self):
    return self._childRect
```

Comment: Your version with the variable still crashes on Windows.  Furthermore, looking at the call sequences using print statements, even in my code, `boundingRect` is called and returns only the new value once `prepareGeometryChange` has been called.  The old soon to be out of date value is never returned.

Comment: Still it dangerous to have such dependency in boundRect method.

A 100% working way to figure out what's happening there is making debug Qt build and run your code under debugger.

Comment: And I still get the crash if I replace my implementation with one based on `QGraphicsItemGroup`.  In that case I don't override `boundingRect` at all.

Comment: @strubbly I've debugged the crash! Check it out.

Comment: Looks like the correct explanation.  If you edit your answer to focus on this (or put it in a separate answer) and I'll probably accept it.

Comment: @strubbly That's better?

Comment: Well not completely - it still says `shape_item.setParentItem(self); # calls boundingRect. but still old value returned!` which isn't actually true - boundingRect is not called at this point.

Comment: @strubbly changed to `could call`

Really this simple thing could cost you hours of debugging.

Comment: I don't agree that there is anything wrong with the original implementation of `boundingRect` or the calls to `prepareGeometryChange` since the `boundingRect` changes correctly by the end of the method call in which `prepareGeometryChange` is called.  However, your debugging has correctly and usefully found the underlying problem and the suggestion to use `selectionChanged` is workable - I have already implemented it.  Thanks!